# How to get Authorization token from a webpage using python requests"

Tags: python, python-requests

How to get Authorization token from a webpage using python requests, i have used requests basicAuth to login, it was worked, but subsequent pages are not accpting te basicAuth, it returns "Authuser is not validated"

There is a login url where i have successfully logged in using python requests's basicAuth. then succeeding pages didn't accept basicAuth credential but it needed authorization header. after looking into browser inspect tool, found out that, this authorization header's value is generated as a part of session local storage. is there any way to get this session value without using webdriver API?

Comment: please share more details as this question is to broad to know the reason of the error

Comment: There is a login url where i have successfully logged in using python requests's basicAuth. then succeeding pages didn't accept basicAuth credential but it needed authorization header. after looking into browser inspect tool, found out that, this authorization header's value is auto generated as a part of session local storage. is there any way to get this session value without using webdriver API?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a requests persistent session

```
import requests
s=requests.Session()
#then simply make the request like you already are
r=s.get(r'https://stackoverflow.com/')
#the cookies are persisted 
s.cookies.get_dict()
>{'prov':......}
```

i can't really get more specific without more info about the site you're using.

Comment: thanks, how the session storage values can be captured using python requests??

Comment: The session will automatically store return cookes and will automatically provide them to subsequents requests using that session.